# Using Caret & recipes to train a model: ERROR Not all variables in the recipe are present

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, r-recipes

I've been trying to train a caret glmnet model for the past few hours but it keeps throwing me errors, my dataset has 15 observations, 3 are factors variables, 11 are numeric and 1 is an integer. I split the dataset into 70/30 train test split.

The dataset has some NA values in it so I tried to impute the NA's in the recipe code, I then piped it to centre and scale the numeric data.

I keep getting an error when I try to preprocess my data using the recipe I have

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(recipes)

data = "data.csv"

'data.frame':   168 obs. of  15 variables:
$ COUNTRY               : Factor w/ 190 levels "Country1","Country10",..: 1 103 114 125 136 147 158 169 180 2 ...
$ GOVERNMENT            : Factor w/ 5 levels "AUTOCRATIC","LEFT"
$ POPULATION            : num  45.4 45.1 80.2 7.8 37.5 ...
$ AGE25PROP             : num  13.6 17.9 11.3 17 15.1 ...
$ AGE55PROP             : num  33.5 36.5 34.4 32.5 33.1 ...
$ POPDENSITY            : num  498 502 494 506 492 ...
$ GDP2019               : num  22.6 22.7 58 56.4 57.4 ...
$ INFANTMORT            : num  16.3 14.2 17.7 NA 15.2 ...
$ DOC10                 : num  22.6 24.1 24.7 NA 26.6 ...
$ VAXRATE               : num  39.5 35.2 61.6 NA 60.6 ...
$ HEALTHCARE_BASIS      : Factor w/ 4 levels "FREE","INSURANCE",
$ HEALTHCARE_COST       : num  4759 15281 NA 5009 NA ...
$ DEATHRATE             : num  21.7 27.3 17.3 16.7 25.2 ...
$ HEALTHCARE_COST_shadow: num  0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
$ na_count              : int  0 0 1 3 1 2 0 1 4 0 ...
```

Test/Train split with "DEATHRATE" as the Y variable

```
subIndex <- caret::createDataPartition(y = data$DEATHRATE, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train <- data[subIndex]
test <- data[-subIndex]
```

Using recipes for preprocessing with "DEATHRATE" as the dependent variable and "COUNTRY" as the id

```
rec <- recipes::recipe("DEATHRATE" ~., data = train) %>%

update_role("COUNTRY", new_role = "id") %>%

step_knnimpute(all_predictors(), neighbours = 5) %>%

step_center(all_numeric(), -has_role("outcome")) %>%

step_scale(all_numeric(), -has_role("outcome"))
```

I always get the error

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

Training the model

```
model <- caret::train(rec, data = train, method = "glmnet")
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Recipes are independent from caret. The first error is telling you to unquote the LHS and "COUNTRY". To use recipes start by defining your steps, as you've done, use `rec <- prep(rec)` to estimate each layer. Then use `juice(rec)` to get train data and `bake(rec, new_data = test)` to get your test data using the steps from the recipe.

Comment: your data has 168 obs but COUNTRY has 190 levels. Perhaps try to remove Country column. This is most likely a problem with your data and without data it will be hard for us to post solutions.